# What is the expression/slang to describe that you suddenly decided to go [travel, change environment]?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, slang

For example you get tired of your job and saying: Oh,[expression, meaning to go] overseas/bar?

Comment: *It's time to hit the road. I'll see you.*

Comment: Screw this. Let's bounce.

Comment: Time to blow this popsicle stand--on which see [this previous question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277594).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Bail*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bail?s=t) could work,

> to give up on or abandon something, as to evade a responsibility:
>   *His partner bailed out before the business failed.*

and

> To leave; cut out, split: *Bruce has bailed from the scene entirely/ Most of my friends had bailed to stay with other relatives*

Alternatively, [*split*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/split?s=t):

> *Slang*. to leave; depart.

and

> to part or separate, as through disagreement; sever relations:

and

> a breach or rupture, as between persons, in a party or organization, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The best word to describe the concept that you're outlining is "[Wanderlust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanderlust)". The reason it has a captial "W" is that it is a loanword from German where all nouns start with a capital letter (like [Weltschmerz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weltschmerz) or [Schadenfreude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schadenfreude)).

You have (or are experiencing) Wanderlust.